# how do i get the sum of hours less than given year and week

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

[image]

how do i get the sum of hours that is less than 2015 week 25

**please note** it has 2014 values also eg: 2014 week 30

Comment: `SELECT SUM(hours) FROM yourTable WHERE year <= 2015 AND week < 25` ... but is there a lower bound on your date range as well?

Comment: ya it has 2014 values also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(hours) WHERE (year = 2015 AND week < 25) OR year < 2015
```

This will capture anything less than that week. Include all weeks/years prior to 2015.

> it has 2014 values also eg: 2014 week 30

Answer (score 1):

try this use mysql `sum()`

```
select sum(hours) 
from table_name 
where year <= 2015 
and week < 25
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

mysql syntax

```
select sum(hours) from table where <= 2015 and week <= 25;
```